# Why is Heroku running dev.py by force in Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, heroku, environment-variables, wagtail

I deployed my Wagtail app on Heroku and want the variable 'DEBUG' to be False on production. I wrote some code in an **init**.py file that tests an environment variable 'ENV' to decide which python file to execute. In production, it should execute only production.py, but it does not. The code actually seems to work because it is not printing my debug message in the case i'm in the development environement, but somehow, dev.py is executed after production.py

I tried removing the variable 'DEBUG' from both files (production.py and dev.py) to put them in **init**.py and define its value according to the environment. It works, DEBUG becomes False in production but it seems like my static files aren't loaded anymore.

```py
#__init__.py
import os

ENV = os.getenv('GLITCHYWARE_ENV', 'dev')

if ENV == 'dev':
    print('DEV')
    from .dev import *
elif ENV == 'prod':
    print('PROD')
    from .production import *
```

The log:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput           
PROD  
The production.py code is executed
The dev.py code is executed #1
```

As you can see, dev.py is executed after production.py, not six times though, i just put many print statements.

Comment: "it seems like my static files aren't loaded anymore" - this is standard behaviour for Django when DEBUG=False. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/static-files/ (specifically the "Serving the files" note), and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets for the suggested approach on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t used Heroku in awhile, but I remember it using the git push origin heroku.

Why not just place dev.py in your .gitignore file in the root of your project. This will prevent it from being uploaded in the first place and you can still us it locally. You can then place your DEBUG variables as they were originally.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, i'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue.

If you're using Heroku, you probably have a Procfile pointing to your `wsgi` configuration

```py
# Procfile

web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi
```

If you analyze this `.wsgi` file, you will notice it has the following definition:

```py
# myproject.wsgi

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings.dev")
```

That means your `.dev` configuration file is loaded by default.

If you're using [django-heroku](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku), all you have to do is to add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` as a **Config Var** on your Heroku app (Heroku > your app > Settings > Config Vars) pointing to the production settings file:

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = myproject.settings.production`

PS: You will also need  a `SECRET_KEY` if you haven't already added.